# AlarmManager problems when changing the system clock

Tags: android, timer, system, clock

I have a service that updates some data every minute. When I change the system clock of the phone or the emulator, the timer executes immediately n times with no delay between them.

Let's suppose that it is 10:00 pm. If I change the time to 11:00pm, the timer runs 60 times one by one with no delay between each run. My service generates HTTP requests so it'll trigger 60 request one by one for 4-5 secs.

What is wrong? I have got the same issue with the `AlarmManager` too. How can I prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue for this

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17486

Answer (score 0):

if u change system time before u have to cancel PendingIntent and restart it